# 5 year support?

Tags: 12.04, xubuntu, lubuntu

I understand that Ubuntu 12.04 will be supported for 5 years.  Is this true for all other variations of ubuntu too?  For example, will lubuntu 12.04, xubuntu 12.04 and the rest also be supported for 5 years?

And if not, does that mean it's better to install ubuntu 12.04 and then maybe

```
sudo aptitude install lxde
```

or

```
sudo aptitude install xfce
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about lxde, but xfce is supported only for 3 years.

And it doesn't matter wheather you will install extra GUI's on your existing desktop.

I think, each desktop will be supported for certen number of years.

Comment: I don't understand.  Ubuntu 12.04 will be supported for 5 years, i.e. from 2012 to 2017.  xfce will be supported for 3 years, i.e. 2012 to 2015.  So if I install xfce on Ubuntu 12.04, when the date 2015 comes, won't the xfce desktop start it's new schedule and be supported on my ubuntu 12.04 install from 2015 to 2018?

Comment: No Xubuntu will be suported till 2015, even if you will install it on top of Ubuntu !

Answer (score 4):

It will not make any difference how you install the various flavors and desktop environments. Each flavor has made a decision on the length of support for 12.04. In the case of Xubuntu, it is officially an LTS and will be supported for three years. Ubuntu is an LTS and will be supported for five years. That means Lubuntu is not an official LTS and yet will also be supported for three years. Please read the release notes for more information about the support time for each flavor.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes

Answer (score 3):

Lubuntu 12.04 will be supported for 18 months only !

Source: The link Charlie provided.

Comment: Specifically, the relevant note is here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/Lubuntu#Support